# U3(30) where 3 divides 30 is isomorphic to which group?

Tags: group-theory

$U(30)=\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$ and $U_3(30)=\{x \in U(30) \mid x \equiv 1 \pmod3\}=
\{1,7,13,19,29\}$.
Since $U_3(30)$ contain 5 elements therefore it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ so it must contain 1 element of order 1 and 4 element of order 5 but order of 3 is coming 4. I think this is not true.

Comment: $U_3(30)$ consists of five elements, is it? What is the definition? Use mathjax properly, and rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

$29$ is not $1$ mod $3$.

Factoring $$\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$$ makes it clear that $$U_3(30) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$$